# How to handle angular app loading error due to unsupported browser?

Tags: javascript, angular, runtime-error

I have an angular application a I want to show custom content for users that are using old, unsupported browser. I don't want to strictly define allowed versions of browsers (or something similar), I would like to just handle error loading root component, or some kind of error in loaded js filed (like syntax error etc.)

I did look for the answer on many portals, but no clue..

Comment: What do you mean with error? Do you mean if the browser does not support js? Or doesn't support specific functions?

Comment: @PatrickCerny if browser doesn't support specific functions. And dont want to handle it with polyfills or by naming needed functions with modernizr...